# Make current date stick to top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have noticed many chat apps like "Slack", "Discord" and "Skype" will display the date `fixed` & `sticky` to the top of the "page" depending what part of the content you are currently scrolled to (in view). I am styling a chat app and am trying to accomplish the same.

Is it possible to tell it with JS to be `position:sticky` for the last one that was in view? Scrolling both up or down?

I created a **[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a8mb5yr7/1/)** of the layout and embedded it into this question also.

Thanks for any help!

```css
body {margin:0; background:lightgray;}
ul, li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
.user {font-weight:bold; padding-right: 5px;}
.msg{
 display:flex;
 background:white;
 margin: 20px;
 margin-left:5px;
 padding: 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
.date {width:100%; background: tomato; text-align:center; padding: 15px; color:white; font-weight:bold; }
```

```html
<ul>


<li class="date">Date: 1/21/2019</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="date">Date: 1/22/2019</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="date">Date: 1/23/2019</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="date">Date: 1/24/2019</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="date">Date: 1/25/2019</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Not quite sure, what it is that you are asking, do you just want to display the datetime on a fixed spot regardless of scroll? I can see multiple date elements, which one do you want to display?

Comment: Are you familiar with slack or discord? It displays the date at the top of every section and makes a new date for every section. I have this working. But they also display the current data "Fixed at the top of the screen" for what portion of the "chat" you are viewing. All chat apps are like this including your phones text messages.

Comment: By section i mean it creates a new date for every day and displays the new chat messages under that date. And if those chat messages are in view it sets the date at the top "fixed"

Comment: so, have 1 date at the top and change it based on the section that is visible?

Comment: Correct - But like in my sample code - the dates still stay where they are.. but should become fixed to the top of the page when that dates section is visible.

Comment: I've got a solution in mind, but before i continue, would it be ok, if i wrapped each section by a div or ul element?

Comment: Its an existing plugin i am modifying. This is my current structure: https://i.postimg.cc/fRP33cs4/strc.png

Comment: Let me check the plugin files to see if changing that structure would be something i can manage. One moment

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/63Pwc0Hw/injectedjs.png - its auto injected - but i think i got my answer below. Thank u!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is this?

I added `position:sticky` and `top:0`

`position:sticky` usable with only top or bottom propertys. (`top` or `bottom` for vertical scroll, `left` or `right` for horizontal scroll)

```css
body {margin:0; background:lightgray;}
ul, li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
.user {font-weight:bold; padding-right: 5px;}
.msg{
 display:flex;
 background:white;
 margin: 20px;
 margin-left:5px;
 padding: 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
.date {width:100%; background: tomato; text-align:center; padding: 15px; color:white; font-weight:bold;
position:sticky;
top:0;
}
```

```html
<ul>


<li class="date">Date: 1/21/2019</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="date">Date: 1/22/2019</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="date">Date: 1/23/2019</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="date">Date: 1/24/2019</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="date">Date: 1/25/2019</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

<li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Hahah YES! Exactly! You are legend my friend.

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Comment: Very elegant. I wasted my time with jQuery and offset().top

Comment: Just know that support for 'sticky' is still fairly poor: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky  If you need better support, 'fixed' might be a better option.  Otherwise if you google for 'css sticky header' there are loads of examples out there too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snipped of that code to achieve what you are doing:https://codepen.io/chrissp26/pen/gBrdo

```js
var stickyHeaders = (function() {

  var $window = $(window),
    $stickies;

  var load = function(stickies) {

    if (typeof stickies === "object" && stickies instanceof jQuery && stickies.length > 0) {

      $stickies = stickies.each(function() {

        var $thisSticky = $(this).wrap('<div class="followWrap" />');

        $thisSticky
          .data('originalPosition', $thisSticky.offset().top)
          .data('originalHeight', $thisSticky.outerHeight())
          .parent()
          .height($thisSticky.outerHeight());
      });

      $window.off("scroll.stickies").on("scroll.stickies", function() {
        _whenScrolling();
      });
    }
  };

  var _whenScrolling = function() {

    $stickies.each(function(i) {

      var $thisSticky = $(this),
        $stickyPosition = $thisSticky.data('originalPosition');

      if ($stickyPosition <= $window.scrollTop()) {

        var $nextSticky = $stickies.eq(i + 1),
          $nextStickyPosition = $nextSticky.data('originalPosition') - $thisSticky.data('originalHeight');

        $thisSticky.addClass("fixed");

        if ($nextSticky.length > 0 && $thisSticky.offset().top >= $nextStickyPosition) {

          $thisSticky.addClass("absolute").css("top", $nextStickyPosition);
        }

      } else {

        var $prevSticky = $stickies.eq(i - 1);

        $thisSticky.removeClass("fixed");

        if ($prevSticky.length > 0 && $window.scrollTop() <= $thisSticky.data('originalPosition') - $thisSticky.data('originalHeight')) {

          $prevSticky.removeClass("absolute").removeAttr("style");
        }
      }
    });
  };

  return {
    load: load
  };
})();

$(function() {
  stickyHeaders.load($(".date"));
});
```

```css
.date {
  width: 100%;
  background: tomato;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.date.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 0;
}

.date.fixed.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: lightgray;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.user {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.msg {
  display: flex;
  background: white;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>


  <div class="date">
    Date: 1/21/2019
  </div>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <div class="date">
    Date: 1/22/2019
  </div>
  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>
  <div class="date">
    Date: 1/23/2019
  </div>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <div class="date">
    Date: 1/24/2019
  </div>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <div class="date">
    Date: 1/25/2019
  </div>>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

  <li class="msg"><span class="user">Username: </span>Hello this is a test message. I am messaging you from messages about messages that message</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use position fixed and give the spacing from the top-right you want and it will work fine.

You might also need Z-index to make sure other elements will not be in front of your fixed element.

More information about positioning can be found [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-use-the-position-property-in-css-to-align-elements-d8f49c403a26)